# Is “X, so Y” a compound or complex sentence?

Tags: grammar, complex-sentences, compound-sentences

Is this a compound or complex sentence? 
I think it might be compound because it has “so”.

> My car battery died, so I called to have it towed for repairs.

Comment: It's a complex sentence consisting of a matrix (main) clause and three embedded (dependent) subordinate clauses. I've bracketed the subordinate clauses: "My car battery died, so [I called [to have it [towed for repairs]]]."

Comment: @BillJ. It would be helpful if you could provide a link to a resource that classifies sentences such as the OP's as _complex_. If the OP is asking in order to clarify a homework task in English class, then it is highly likely that the expected answer will be that the sentence is a _compound_ sentence - as expounded in the  answer below.

Comment: Whatever else, that clearly doesn't consist of "a matrix (main) clause and three embedded (dependent) subordinate clauses", nor anything like that.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Really? Then how do you account for the subordinate content clause "I called to have it towed for repairs", the subordinate infinitival clause "to have it towed for repairs", and the subordinate past  participial clause "towed for repairs".

Comment: @BillJ - Although those verbs are in some way 'subordinate', the phrases *are not adverbial*, and that is a requirement for a dependent clause.  'So' is not a subordinating conjunction.  Its phrase is independent *because* it cannot be moved without changing the meaning (dependent phrases can be moved around within the clause that they depend on).

Comment: @AmI A subordinate clause is one that is dependent on some other element in the sentence, not one that is necessarily adverbial, or moveable. Content clauses, for example, are the default kind of finite subordinate clause, but they are complements, not adjuncts, and they are not usually moveable. And relative clauses are subordinate, but certainly not adjuncts, nor moveable. Likewise comparative clauses, not to mention many kinds of non-finite clauses too. I take "so" as a prep that takes a content clause as complement. It's the PP that's an adjunct, not the clause.

Comment: @BillJ - We should not get hung up on defining 'subordinate' (and whether conj is a subset of prep).  The OP question is about compound/complex distinction, and that hinges on independent+independent vs independent+dependent distinction.  Also, *content clauses* that are expressed using non-finite syntax are not usually even considered as *clauses* in the [in]dependency analysis.

Comment: @Aml You asserted that dependent clauses are adverbial, and I disagree with that for the reasons I gave in my last comment. The OP's sentence contains subordinate (dependent) clauses and hence is a complex one. Content clauses are finite and always subordinate: in "so [I called to have it towed for repairs]", the bracketed element is a subordinate content clause serving as complement of "so". It contains the further embedded subordinate infinitival clause "to have it towed for repairs" which in turn contains the further embedded subordinate past participial clause "towed for repairs".

Answer (score -1):

It is a compound sentence.

From study.com [Link](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-a-compound-sentence-examples-definition-quiz.html):

> Definition
>
> A compound sentence is a sentence that has at least two independent clauses joined by a comma, semicolon or conjunction. An independent clause is a clause that has a subject and verb and forms a complete thought.
>
> An example of a compound sentence is, 'This house is too expensive, and that house is too small.' This sentence is a compound sentence because it has two independent clauses, 'This house is too expensive' and 'that house is too small' separated by a comma and the conjunction 'and.'
>
> Compound Sentences and Meaning
>   When independent clauses are joined with coordinators (also called coordinating conjunctions) commas and semicolons, they do more than just join the clauses. They add meaning and flow to your writing. First let's look at the coordinators you can use to join independent clauses. They are:
>
> - For
> - And
> - Nor
> - But
> - Or
> - Yet
> - So"

Examples of compound sentences from softschools.com [Link](http://www.softschools.com/examples/grammar/compound_sentences_examples/442/):

> 1. Sarah walked to class, but Kevin ran.
> 2. I want hamburgers, but Lois wants pizza.
> 3. The photographer held up a bear, and the little boy smiled.
> 4. I fell out of the bed, so Mom came to check on me.
> 5. The dog buried his bone, and the cat sniffed around it.
> 6. I was late; however, the class had not started.
> 7. I left my bag on the bus; therefore, I did not have a pencil.
> 8. Can I go home with you, so we can do our homework together?
> 9. It was very hot outside, and the ice cream melted.
> 10. Our team tried hard, but we lost the game."

Comment: Avoid copying an answer from elsewhere. “[You have to write an actual answer, in your own words. A post that consists only of copied text … is not your work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077 "“Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?” – SE Meta")”.